# Certain national characters blocked in Sublime Text 3

Tags: internationalization, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with Polish keyboard (both hardware and keyboard set in Windows 7) and I'm unable to enter "ć" ("c" with Polish accent -- <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) and "Ś" (capital "s" with accent -- <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>).

Out of entire Polish language-specific set of eighteen characters (`ęóąśłżźćńĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ`) these two are kind of strange excpetion in Sublime Text 3.

What can be causing this and is there any workaround, exect for copy-pasting these letters from clippboard?

I'm pretty sure, that this is not caused by some conflicts in keyboards binding between core editor and plugins (I've installed a dozen of them), because I added these two lines to `Preferences > Key Bindings -- User`:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+c"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "ć"} },
{ "keys": ["shift+alt+s"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "Ś"} },
```

And it didn't help even a bit (any possible conflicts would be overwritten by above configuration change).

This problem seems to be originating in core code of Sublime Text 3. I don't know, if and how does it affects other languages, that uses language-specific characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 doesn't make any difference between pressing <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>. This is a classic bug, found in many editors, that makes life of non-Latin alphabets users just a little bit nightmare.

It turned out, that these two key bindings were in conflict with keyboard shortcuts defined by one of the plugins (by a [Modific](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Modific) in my case). To workaround this one must redefine these keys in user keyboard settings:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+c"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "ć"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+s"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "Ś"} },
```

This will solve a problem, but disable `Ctrl+Alt+C` shortcut used to preview committed code for current line. You need to define a new key binding for it or stop using this keyboard combination.

Comment: In my case FileHeader plugin steal my "ą"

Comment: And in my case MarkdownEditing was stealing "ś"

Comment: Pylinter steals ć,ź,ż

Comment: FileManager steals "ń", it can be disabled by `create_keybinding_enabled` option.